# Can I upload a sketch of a UI and ask for opinions?

Tags: discussion, question

Is it ok to ask for opinions about a specific UI example? or do questions have to stay objective and theoretical?

Comment: Just as an FYI there is a wonderful community (and still pretty young) over at http://conceptfeedback.com where you can submit such designs and get all the opinionated feedback you want - including some from yours truly. :-)

Comment: @JoelGlovier, the conceptfeedback.com website has been shut down.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would be OK to upload an image of a UI, but I would still ask a very specific question about it. Not just 'what do you think?' but 'what do you think about the position of this button?'.

There's a million different UI's, and if everyone uploads theirs and asks for opinions, it's going to be a huge mess. Asking specific questions is going to narrow this down, and opens possibilities for reuse. Similar UI elements might be found in other applications as well, and questions about them will be of use to others.

Comment: +1 Agree. A UI sketch is ideal when used to clarify the author's **question**. This should *not* become a *"what do you think of my design?"* or *"do my work for me"* site.

Comment: +1 also agree, and I submit that if you're having specific problems and ask about them with a UI sketch, you're bound to get some feedback on other elements as well. This makes the problem both findable, and other problems more discoverable.