# Soliciting UX feedback

Tags: discussion

Say theoretically I made my own web site and I wanted genuine feedback from the community regarding its overall experience. Obviously anyone who asks "Look at my site and tell me what you think" on SE is going to be downvoted and flagged to oblivion for being too localized.

- Is there a place one can properly obtain feedback from the UX community?
- Are there certain phrases/formats one can form a question that wouldn't immediately be closed as 'too localized'?

Answer (score 5):

A good start would be to visit the chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/389/ux-chat

Once you get some general feedback from us there, you can identify some specific quetsions you'd like to ask the community on UX itself.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was asked here: [Can I upload a sketch of a UI and ask for opinions?](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12/can-i-upload-a-sketch-of-a-ui-and-ask-for-opinions)

As @Rahul said, you could start by asking for general feedback in the chat. Another option would be going to a page as [Concept Feedback](http://www.conceptfeedback.com/) where you can get this type of feedback.

Then, after getting some feedback there, you could ask a more specific question about it here, such as "What is better for this user rating input, thumbs up and down or a five star system?".